# Proving a set of coordinates is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Here is a homework problem I have from my Abstract Algebra - Number Theory class. I've reprinted it verbatim. I'm a little uncertain how to approach this problem given that the elements of the set $G$ are coordinates which satisfy a given equation.

For example, since the identity element for a group is unique, would I merely set up an equation of the form
$$(x,y) * (e,e) = (x + 7 y, x +y)$$
and solve for $e$ in order to determine the identity element? Or will I have two identity elements, $(e_1, e_2)$ to plug into the equation above? Any additional pointers would be appreciated.

$\textbf{Problem:}$
Let $G$ be the set of pairs $(x,y)$ of integers for which $x^2 - 7 y^2 = 1$. If $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ are in $G$, define $(x,y) * (u,v) = (xu + 7 yv, xv +yu)$.

(1)Exhibit an identity element for this operation on the set $G$.

(2)Determine if each element of $G$ has an inverse (in $G$) with respect to this operation.

(3)Determine if $G$ is closed under this operation.

(4)Let $p>7$ be a prime number. Let $H$ be the set of pairs $(x,y)$ of elements of $Z_p$ for which $x^2 - 7 y^2 = 1 \mod p$. For $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ two such elements of $H$, define $(x,y)*(u,v) =((xu + 7 yv) \mod p, (xv+yu) \mod p)$. Answer the the above three questions for the set $H$ with this new modular operation.

Comment: Your identity element does not have to have both numbers the same. For this particular problem, the numbers are different.

Comment: Hint: How should you choose $u,v$ so that $xu+7yv$ is always $=x$, no matter what $y$ is?

Comment: $(x, y)=(1,0)$ is an obvious solution to $x^2 -7y^2 =1$ and $(x,y)*(1,0) = (x,y) , (\forall x,y \in G)$. I wonder how I can prove that $(1,0)$ is the only solution and therefore it is its own inverse? Or how to go about finding a general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlights:

$$\begin{cases}xu+7yv=x\\{}\\xv+yu=y\end{cases}\iff
\begin{pmatrix}u&7v\\v&u\end{pmatrix}\binom xy=\binom xy$$

The above matrix's determinant is $\;u^2-7v^2=1\;$ , so its inverse is

$$\begin{pmatrix}u&-7v\\-v&u\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\ldots$$

Also

$$(xu+7yv)^2-7(xv+yu)^2=x^2u^2+14xyuv+49y^2v^2-7x^2v^2-14xuyv-7y^2u^2=$$

$$x^2(u^2-7v^2)-7y^2(u^2-7v^2)=\ldots\text{ and etc.}$$

Comment: So, $(1,0)$ is the identity element. And I can see how the operation is closed. It seems that from the inverse matrix we obtain the fact that $$(xu+7yv, xv+yu)*(ux-7vy, -vx+uy)=(a, b)$$ where $(a,b) = (1,0)$ but when I perform the algebra to solve for $a$, I end up with $$x^2(u^2-7v^2) + 7y^2(u^2-7v^2)= x^2+7y^2$$ How do I show that $x^2+7y^2=1$?  Is this a correct line of reasoning, or is it enough to show that multiplying the two matrices together obtains the identity matrix?

Comment: Also, when I solve for $b$ I obtain $$2xyu^2 - 14xyu^2 = 2xy(u^2-7v^2) = 2xy$$ It seems obvious that by substituting $x=1$ and $y=0$ into my equations for $a,b$ that I will obtain the result I want. How do I justify doing that, though? Or am I way off the mark?

Comment: You have a "plus" where I have a "minus" (your comment's second line of caclulations): that's all the difference, @JoePirus

Comment: Here's my interpretation of your answer: Between "Highlights" and "so..." is the process for finding an inverse element for any element of $G$. Between "Also" and "... and etc." is the process of showing that $G$ is closed under the operation. By plugging $$(xu+7yv, xv+yu)$$ into the equation $x^2 -7y^2=1$ we show that it is a solution and therefore is an element of $G$. Correct? My problem seems to be performing the operation $$(xu+7yv,xv+yu)*(ux-7yv, -vx+uy)$$ and obtaining the identity element.